# the orthogonal complement of the set of all polynomials of odd degree

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

What is the orthogonal complement in $L^2([ -π, π])$ of the set of all
polynomials of odd degree?
It is the set of all functions in $L^2([-π, π])$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)$ almost
everywhere.
But I can not show it. How to?

Comment: What is the definition of an orthogonal complement? Can you apply it?

Comment: Do you really mean polynomials of odd degree, or monomials of odd degree? Have a look at $x+1$

Comment: I mean polynomials of odd degree.

Comment: @user201984: If you mean polynomial of odd degree as you have stated, then your claim in the question that the orthogonal complement is the set of all function in $L^2([-\pi, \pi])$ such that $f(x) = f(-x)$ almost everywhere is **false**. Using Thomas' suggestion, let $g(x) = x + 1$ and $f(x) = 1$, then 

$$\langle f, g\rangle = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}1(x+1)dx = \left[\frac{1}{2}x^2 + x\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\pi^2 + \pi\right) - \left(\frac{1}{2}(-\pi)^2 - \pi\right) = 2\pi \neq 0.$$

Comment: Thank you.What happens if we consider monomials of odd degree؟